# NodeJS / Express: what is "app.use"?

Tags: node.js, express

In the [docs for the NodeJS `express` module](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), the example code has `app.use(...)`.

What is the `use` function and where is it defined?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337572/can-someone-explain-what-middleware-is-and-what-app-use-actually-means

Comment: These type of questions can be answered by reading the documentation.

Comment: the documentation is a bit cryptic for a beginner

Comment: Possible duplicate above is referencing each other

Comment: The documentation is completely unclear

Comment: @KansaiRobot I'm a beginner and its nice to see someone actually thinks its not straightforward!

Comment: just wanted to add, as another beginner, it's also fairly unclear to me as well

Comment: By the way, being a "beginner" doesn't mean you don't know how to code. It just means you're a beginner at Nodejs Express. The documentation seems written by people so familiar with the project that they don't know how to explain the basics.

Answer (score 474, accepted):

The app object is instantiated on creation of the Express server. It has a ***middleware** stack* that can be customized in [`app.configure()`(this is now deprecated in version 4.x)](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x).

To setup your middleware, you can invoke [`app.use(<specific_middleware_layer_here>)`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) for every middleware layer that you want to add (it can be generic to all paths, or triggered only on specific path(s) your server handles), and it will add  onto your [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) middleware stack. Middleware layers can be added one by one in multiple invocations of `use`, or even all at once in series with one invocation.
See [`use` documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) for more details.

To give an example for conceptual understanding of Express Middleware, here is what my app middleware stack (app.stack) looks like when logging my app object to the console as JSON:

```
stack: 
   [ { route: '', handle: [Function] },
     { route: '', handle: [Function: static] },
     { route: '', handle: [Function: bodyParser] },
     { route: '', handle: [Function: cookieParser] },
     { route: '', handle: [Function: session] },
     { route: '', handle: [Function: methodOverride] },
     { route: '', handle: [Function] },
     { route: '', handle: [Function] } ]
```

As you might be able to deduce, I called `app.use(express.bodyParser())`, `app.use(express.cookieParser())`, etc, which added these express middleware 'layers' to the middleware stack. Notice that the routes are blank, meaning that when I added those middleware layers I specified that they be triggered on any route. If I added a custom middleware layer that only triggered on the path `/user/:id` that would be reflected as a string in the `route` field of that middleware layer object in the stack printout above.

*Each layer is essentially adding a function that specifically handles something to your flow through the middleware.*

E.g. by adding `bodyParser`, *you're ensuring your server handles incoming requests through the express middleware*. So, *now parsing the body of incoming requests is part of the procedure that your middleware takes when handling incoming requests* -- all because you called `app.use(bodyParser)`.

Comment: thank you.  would it be so difficult for the express folks to explain this in their API docs?

Comment: So you're saying that when a request is received the data is passed through those parsers before hitting the actual service. So for example: Valid Request->Authentication->ProcessesRequest->ServResponse

**USE** would control those steps in a specific order and not execute them parallel?

Comment: So is app.use() dependency injection in action?

Comment: When is the function that is sent to app.use called? After creating the express server or for every request?

Comment: Projects generated by express use `app.use` to load routes. I don't consider my routes middleware, so is this another acceptable use case?

Comment: Very well explained. To answer CyberMen question, yes on each request your stack executes in the order manner. something like this.
```
let self = this;
stack.map(function(e,i) {
  if(e.route === 'incomingroute') {
   self.call(e,self);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Jon In Express there is **only** middlewares. Express.js does not implement anything else apart from a middleware (plugin) architecture. The middleware can be anything. A route is just a special type of middleware (Note that `app.get`, `app.post` etc are just convenience helpers around `app.use`. You can in fact load middlewares using `app.get` instead of `app.use` if you don't want the middleware to handle post requests)

Comment: @TimoHuovinen Yes. For every request. The stack is actually a tree which can branch depending on the routing path (yes, you can route even middlewares, not just "routes", IMHO the community deciding to call endpoints routes is a mistake since the language can get confusing if you want to route non-endpoints (non-routes)). The stack/tree will keep calling the next function until if finds a middleware (including "routes") that no longer call `next()` (no longer in the "middle")

Comment: @KevinC. No, it is not dependency injection. It is a plugin architecture. Generally this kind of architecture is called a filter system / filter pipeline / pipe and filter. In Express the pipe is the `next()` callback each middleware is expected to call to pass processing to the next function in the pipeline. The routing system (the first argument to `app.use()`) allows the pipeline to branch depending on URL

Answer (score 143):

Each **app.use(middleware)** is called every time a request is sent to the server.

Comment: Your single sentence answer is instantly understandable and more helpful than the other multi-paragraph explanations.

Comment: Only thing that it should be invoked before `app.get`. Else it never gets called.

Answer (score 57):

[`use`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/proto.html#app.use) is a method to configure the middleware used by the routes of the Express HTTP server object.  The method is defined as part of [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) that Express is based upon.

[Update](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) Starting with version 4.x, Express no longer depends on [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/).

The middleware functions that were previously included with Express are now in separate modules; see the [list of middleware functions](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware).

Comment: And the online docs are here: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/proto.html#app.use

Comment: Would it be efficient if a Node middleware instantiates objects? Would this mean that on every request, that middleware instantiates new objects? Do the old objects get discarded? For example `app.use(function(){ var object = new SomeConstructor; next(); })`

Comment: @CMCDragonkai It's fine to instantiate objects on every request. They'll get garbage collected so long as you're not storing references to the objects outside the scope of your request handler.

Comment: @AlexanderBird thx for the links (the 1st one is broken now though). For the record, just the begining of the doc in the 2nd link says "Utilize the given middleware handle to the given route, defaulting to /. This "route" is the mount-point for the middleware, when given a value other than / the middleware is only effective when that segment is present in the request's
pathname. For example if we were to mount a function at /admin, it would
be invoked on /admin, and /admin/settings, however it would
not be invoked for /, or /posts". Simple :)

Answer (score 33):

**app.use()** acts as a middleware in express apps. Unlike **app.get()** and **app.post()** or so, you actually can use **app.use()** without specifying the request URL. In such a case what it does is, it gets executed every time no matter what URL's been hit.

Answer (score 19):

app.use() used to Mounts the middleware function or mount to a specified path,the middleware function is executed when the base path matches.

**For example:**
if you are using app.use() in indexRouter.js , like this:

```
//indexRouter.js

var adsRouter = require('./adsRouter.js');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/ads', adsRouter);
}
```

In the above code app.use() mount the path on '/ads' to adsRouter.js.

**Now in adsRouter.js**

```
// adsRouter.js

var router = require('express').Router();
var controllerIndex = require('../controller/index');
router.post('/show', controllerIndex.ads.showAd);
module.exports = router;
```

**in adsRouter.js, the path will be like this for ads- '/ads/show', and then it will work according to controllerIndex.ads.showAd().**

**app.use([path],callback,[callback]) :**
we can add a callback on the same.

```
app.use('/test', function(req, res, next) {

  // write your callback code here.

    });
```

Comment: I'd use "map" in place of "mount", easier to understand.

Answer (score 13):

```
app.use(function middleware1(req, res, next){
   // middleware1 logic
}, function middleware2(req, res, next){
   // middleware2 logic
}, ... middlewareN);
```

**app.use** is a way to register ***middleware or chain of middlewares*** (or multiple middlewares) before executing any end route logic or intermediary route logic depending upon order of middleware registration sequence.

**Middleware:** forms chain of **functions/middleware-functions** with **3 parameters req, res, and next**. next is callback which refer to next middleware-function in chain and in case of last middleware-function of chain next points to first-middleware-function of next registered middlerare-chain.

Answer (score 13):

`app.use()` handles all the middleware functions.
What is middleware?
Middlewares are the functions which work like a door between two all the routes.

For instance:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log("middleware ran");
    next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Home route");
});
```

When you visit `/` route in your console the two message will be printed. The first message will be from middleware function. If there is no `next()` function passed then only middleware function runs and other routes are blocked.

Comment: From Review: Do we really need yet another answer in this thread?

Answer (score 9):

app.use() works like that:

1. Request event trigered on node http server instance.
2. express
   does some of its inner manipulation with req object.
3. This is when
   express starts doing things you specified with app.use

which very simple.

And only then express will do the rest of the stuff like routing.

Answer (score 6):

The .use() method in express is a *middleware handler. An Express application is essentially a series of middleware function calls.

An Express application can use 5 different types of middleware, of which these two are majorly used:

1. Application-level middleware
2. Router-level middleware

App.use() is used to bind *application-level middleware to an instance of the app object which is instantiated on the creation of the Express server (router.use() for router-level middleware).

Syntax : `app.use(path, middleware function/s)`

Here, the path is optional. When no path is specified the function gets executed every time the app receives a request, irrespective of which URL has been hit.

*Example:
Auth middleware   -   In a To-Do app, once an already created user logs in, he is provided with a JWT token, which must be verified every time the user makes a GET, PUT, PATCH, POST or DELETE request.

```
app.use("/api/*", verifyToken(req, res, next): void {
const jwt: string = req.headers['x-token-header'];
if (!jwt) {
  res.status(403).send({ message: 'No token provided!' });
} else {
  jsonwebtoken.verify(jwt, config.get('secretString'), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(403).send(err);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
});
```

Here, the path /api has been added to differentiate from requests that do not need a JWT authentication such as sign up and log in (since we don't want the middleware to be executed when there's no need for authentication).

*Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next.

Syntax of a middleware: `function(req, res, next)`

Comment: This explanations is more precisely answered the question.

Comment: so for signin or singup page, we cannot use route path 
"/api/login"    "/api/signup"  ?

Comment: @AkinZeman, yes in this particular scenario, paths that start with /api all need a JWT token, whereas the login & signup paths don't need the token.

Answer (score 4):

In express if we 
import express from "express"
and use app = express();
then app having all functionality of express

if we use app.use()

with any module/middleware function to use in whole express project

Answer (score 4):

**app.use** is woks as **middleware** for app request.
syntax

```
app.use('pass request format',function which contain request response onject)
```

example

```
app.use('/',funtion(req,res){
 console.log(all request pass through it);
// here u can check your authentication and other activities.
})
```

also you can use it in case of routing your request.

```
app.use('/', roting_object);
```

Answer (score 3):

`app.use` is a function requires middleware. For example:

```
 app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
       console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
        next();
     });
```

This example shows the middleware function installed in the `/user/:id` path. This function is executed for any type of HTTP request in the `/user/:id` path.

It is similar to the REST Web Server, just use different `/xx` to represent different actions.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but since someone else already said all that information I won't upvote this one. I don't think I need every explanation of what express `use` can do; I just needed to know that's what it was (and any context knowledge to know how to go research more myself).

Answer (score 3):

`app.use()` is a method that allows us to register a middleware.

The middleware method is like an interceptor in java, this method always executes for all requests.

Purpose and use of middleware:-

1. To check if the session expired or not
2. for user authentication and authorization
3. check for cookie (expiry date)
4. parse data before the response

Comment: Middleware is the function passed into app.use().

Answer (score 2):

Middleware is a general term for software that serves to "glue together" so
app.use is a method to configure the middleware, for example: to parse and handle the body of request:
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
there are many middlewares you can use in your express application
just read the doc :
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 2):

app.use applies the specified middleware to the main app middleware stack. When attaching middleware to the main app stack, the order of attachment matters; if you attach middleware A before middleware B, middleware A will always execute first. You can specify a path for which a particular middleware is applicable. In the below example, “hello world” will always be logged before “happy holidays.”

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('hello world')
  next()
})

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('happy holidays')
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It enables you to use any middleware ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337572/what-does-middleware-and-app-use-actually-mean-in-expressjs)) like `body_parser`,`CORS` etc. Middleware can make changes to `request` and `response` objects. It can also execute a piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe all that information is already captured in other answers

Answer (score 2):

You can also create your own middleware function like

```
app.use( function(req, res, next) {
  // your code 
  next();
})
```

It contains three parameters `req`, `res`, `next` 
You can also use it for authentication and validation of input params to keep your 
    controller clean.

`next()` is used for go to next middleware or route. 
You can send the response from middleware

Answer (score 2):

app.use is Application level middleware

Bind application-level middleware to an instance of the app object by using the app.use() and app.METHOD() functions, where METHOD is the HTTP method of the request that the middleware function handles (such as GET, PUT, or POST) in lowercase.

you can use to check all requests, for example, you want to check token/access token you need to write a middleware by using app.use to check the token in the request.

This example shows a middleware function with no mount path. The function is executed every time the app receives a request.

```
var app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now())
  next()
})
```

reference from https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: app.use() is not middleware. Middleware is the function passed into app.use()

Answer (score 2):

***app.use(path, middleware)*** is used to call middleware function that needs to be called before the route is hit for the corresponding path. Multiple middleware functions can be invoked via an app.use.

***app.use(‘/fetch’, enforceAuthentication)*** -> enforceAuthentication middleware fn will be called when a request ***starting with ‘/fetch’*** is received. It can be */fetch/users*, */fetch/ids/{id}*, etc

Some middleware functions might have to be called irrespective of the request. For such cases, a path is not specified, and since the the path defaults to ***/*** and every request starts with ***/***, this middleware function will be called for all requests.

***app.use(() => { // Initialize a common service })***

**next()** fn needs to be called within each middleware function when multiple middleware functions are passed to ***app.use***, else the next middleware function won’t be called.

reference : http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use

Note: The documentation says we can bypass middleware functions following the current one by calling ***next('route')*** within the current middleware function, but this technique ***didn't work for me within app.use*** but ***did work with app.METHOD*** like below. So, fn1 and fn2 were called but not fn3.

```
app.get('/fetch', function fn1(req, res, next)  {
    console.log("First middleware function called"); 
        next();
    }, 
    function fn2(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Second middleware function called"); 
        next("route");
    }, 
    function fn3(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Third middleware function will not be called"); 
        next();
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

In simple words `app.use()` is a function that takes another function (callback) as a parameter and runs every time, when the request is sent to the express app/server.

The function passed inside app.use is also called middleware, middleware is just a fancy name for a function that exists in express app and has three parameters request, response and next. You can read more about [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Middleware are called between request and response cycle. If you want a middleware to be applied on all the routes then you can use `app.use()` or do some validation, error checking and other things.

Answer (score 2):

`app.use(req, res, next)` is an API that allows us to add one or more middlewares to the request pipeline of express. A middleware is a function that has a defined signature, and through that, you can modify or end the request, returning a response according to a condition that you program. For example, I can call res.end() and finish the request to the client. Middlewares are executed in the order they're added. I can simply decorate the req object, adding or removing properties, for example, authenticating an user and setting req.user = 'any user of database', and calling next(), the next middleware will begin its execution, receiving the same instance of req, res, next.

Answer (score 2):

app.use() acts as a middleware, where using it you can declare route specific middlewares

```
// in server.js
import Users from '../routes/Users.js'
import Posts from '../routes/Posts.js'
...
app.use('/users', Users)
app.use('/posts', Posts)
...
```

along with that you may use it to declare global middlewares

```
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind application-level middleware to an instance of the app object by using the app.use() and app.METHOD() functions, where METHOD is the HTTP method of the request that the middleware function handles (such as GET, PUT, or POST) in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

In short app.use() supports all type of requests [eg:get,post,...]
so its mostly used to setup middelware.
or can be used for when the routes and functions seperated

example:

```
app.use("/test",functionName)
```

and functionName is located in different file

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe all that information is already captured in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

app.use 
is created by express(nodejs middleware framework ) 
app.use is use to execute any specific query  at intilization process

**server.js(node)**
var app = require('express');
**`app.use(bodyparser.json())`**

so the basically app.use function called every time when ***server up***

Answer (score 1):

You can use `app.use('/apis/test', () => {...})` for writing middleware for your api, to handle one or some action (authentication, validation data, validation tokens, etc) before it can go any further or response with specific status code when the condition that you gave was not qualified.

Example:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Your code to handle data here
  next()
})
```

More detail is, this part actually an anonymous function for you to write the logic on runtime

```
function (req, res, next) {
   // Your code to handle data here
   next()
}
```

You can split it into another function from another file and using `module.export` to use

`next()` here for the logic that if you handle everything is fine then you can use then for the program to continue the logic that its used to.

Answer (score 1):

The app.use() function is used to mount the specified middleware function(s) at the path which is being specified. It is mostly used to set up middleware for your application.
Syntax
`app.use(path, callback)`
Parameters:

1. `path`: It is the path for which the middleware function is being called.   It can be a string representing a path or path pattern or regular expression pattern to match the paths.
2. `callback`: It is a middleware function or a series/array of middleware functions.

Answer (score 1):

`app.use()` will be called for every request: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a set of routes that our site can handle

```
app.get('/1/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('page1');
});

app.get('/2/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('page2');
});
```

Obviously, if an address is requested that we do not process, then a 404 error should be returned. Express, however, does not do this by default. But it's easy to implement.

The special method `app.use` will help us with this. It allows you to intercept all raw addresses

Let's use this method to return a 404 error

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send('not found');
});
```

Now let's place our construction after all `app.get`

```
app.get('/1/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('page1');
});

app.get('/2/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('page2');
});

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send('not found');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The app. use() function is used to mount the specified middleware function(s) at the path which is being specified. It is mostly used to set up middleware for your application.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, it acts as a middleware in your routing.

Let's say for any single route, you want to call multiple url or perform multiple functions internally before sending the response.
you can use this middleware and pass your route and perform all internal operations.

```
syntax:
app.use( function(req, res, next) {
  // code
 next();
})
```

**next** is optional, you can use to pass the result using this parameter to the next function.

Answer (score 0):

app.use() is the application middleware.
Bind application-level middleware to an instance of the app object by using the app. use() and app. METHOD() functions, where METHOD is the HTTP method of the request that the middleware function handles (such as GET, PUT, or POST)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var PORT = 3000;

// This middleware will not allow the
// request to go beyond it
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Middleware called")
    next();
});
    
// Requests will never reach this route
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
    console.log("/user request called");
    res.send('Hello test');
});

app.listen(PORT, function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});
```