# Difference between app.use and app.get *in proxying*

Tags: reactjs, express, http-proxy

I'm hoping to better understand the difference between express's `app.get()` and `app.use()`.

I understand that app.use applies to all HTTP verbs.

I have also read that "[`app.use()` adds middleware rather than a route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27162596/554807)"

I'd like to understand why this fact causes this behaviour...

I have an express API server that needs to proxy a React development web server.

This means that all routes that are not API routes have to be proxied.

When I proxy the routes like this, it works:

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

module.exports = function set_react_catchall_routes(app) { 
    /* Final route to send anything else to react server. */
    app.get('*', proxy('localhost:3000'));
    app.post('*', proxy('localhost:3000'));
}
```

But when I do this it does not work:

```
    app.use('*', proxy('localhost:3000'));
```

Specifically, the "index" page is proxied and served up, with content like this:

```
 <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
 </body>
```

and the client requests the javascript react bundle, but then "nothing happens".

I'm reasonably sure that there aren't "other" HTTP requests involved when it does work (other than GET and POST) because none are logged.

So what would be the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this logging at the top, it should help to clarify what's going on:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // req.path will be '/static/js/bundle.js'
    console.log('path1: ' + req.path);

    next();
});

app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
    // req.path will be '/'
    console.log('path2: ' + req.path);

    next();
});

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    // req.path will be '/static/js/bundle.js'
    console.log('path3: ' + req.path);

    next();
});
```

When you use `app.use` it will strip off the matching section of `req.path`. If you don't specify a path (logging section 1) it won't strip anything off. Similarly section 3 is using `app.all` (`app.get`, etc. all work the same way) which doesn't change `req.path` either. It's section 2 that's the kicker.

To understand why this happens consider this example:

```js
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/profile', ...);

app.use('/user', router);
```

When a request comes in for `/user/profile` the `app.use` will strip off the `/user` part of the path. As far as `router` is concerned the path is just `/profile`.

To quote the docs, http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path

> When called from a middleware, the mount point is not included in req.path.

The path for a call to `app.use` is a bit like a 'starts with' and anything that matches is thrown away. For `*` that matches everything so it throws away everything.

If you take a quick dive into the source code for `express-http-proxy` you'll see that it uses `req.path` to determine the path of the proxy request. If you just use `app.use` without a path it should work fine.

There are some other request properties that are similarly relevant to understanding `app.use`:

- `req.url` is similar to `req.path` but with the query string included. Just like `req.path` it will have the section matching the `mountpath` removed by `app.use`. Note that the Express `Request` inherits the `url` property from Node's `http.IncomingMessage` so it isn't explicitly listed in the Express documentation.
- `req.originalUrl` starts off the same as `req.url` but it will not be changed by `app.use`.
- `req.baseUrl` is used to store the section of the path that has been removed by `app.use`.

See [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl) for `req.originalUrl` for more details on all three of these properties.

Comment: Far out, awesome answer, _exactly_ what I needed to know, clearly explained!