# node express: is path always optional?

Tags: node.js, express

According to the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) for `express`, the `path` parameter is optional for [`app.use`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use), so to apply the middleware to any incoming request you can write:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('ANY request');
  next();
});
```

But for [`app.get`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method) the `path` parameter is apparently not optional, so to apply the middleware to any incoming `GET` request you have to write:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('GET request');
  next();
});
```

But I find that it doesn't complain if I *do* miss out the path:

```
app.get(function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('GET request');
  next();
});
```

So, are the above two definitions equivalent, or is the second one doing something different to the first one?

I'm also not sure of the difference between specifying `/` or `*` as the `path`:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('GET request');
  next();
});
```

So, in summary, is there any difference between `app.get('/', fn)` and `app.get('*', fn)` and `app.get(fn)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly, there are two methods called `app.get`:

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get

One is the converse to `app.set`, the other is the one for handling GET requests. In practice JS only allows a single method, so internally Express checks how many arguments are passed to work out which one you meant:

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/351396f971280ab79faddcf9782ea50f4e88358d/lib/application.js#L474

So while using `app.get(fn)` might not complain, it won't actually work as a route because it'll be treating it as the other form of `get`.

The difference between `app.get('*', ...)` and `app.get('/', ...)` is that the `*` will match any path whereas `/` will only match the exact path `/` (and nothing more). This is different from `app.use`, where the path is treated like a 'starts with'.

You may find the answer I gave here helpful to understand how paths differ between `get` and `use`: [Difference between app.use and app.get *in proxying*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965135/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-proxying).

Comment: Thanks.  I saw the other single-argument `app.get` but thought that, with some type-checking at the top of the function, it could maybe distinguish between a string and a function passed in, and treat the latter as a catch-all route... equivalent to `app.get('*', fn)`... but that isn't the case?  And as for the difference between `*` and `/` I was thoroughly thrown off track by `app.use` where, like you say, `/` is treated like 'starts with'... very confusing that it is different to `app.get('/', fn)`!

Comment: `app.get`, `app.post`, etc. all work the same way, they all require a path. If you read through the source code you'll see that they all just pass through to an internal router, which calls `router.route` with the path. Nowhere is a default path applied. I imagine that part of the reason for this is that there isn't a particularly good default choice for the path. For middleware (`app.use`) it makes sense to default to 'everything' but for routes registered with `app.get`, etc. it's much less common to want to match 'everything'. I agree it would be helpful if `app.get` did a type-check.