# What is the difference between get/post/... and use

Tags: express, middleware

All:

I am new to Express 4 router.

When I tried some login/signup example, I got one question about the .use and .get/.post function:

I saw sometimes it uses:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Welcome");
});
```

and in main app, we use it like:

```
app.use("/", router);
```

While some other time,  it uses:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//here the router uses .use() function rather than .get/.post
router.use('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Welcome");
});
```

and in main app, we use it like:

```
app.use("/", router);
```

So I am wondering what is the difference between them, **does the .use() just a general name for all of get/post/put/... together?**

I find this post: [Difference between app.use and app.get in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js)

But still not feel easy to understand this....

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between app.use and app.get in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to what Jonathan Lonowski said in the posted link, it might help to not compare `use` to `get` and `post`, but to compare it to `all` because both `all` and `use` work regardless of the HTTP verb used while that's obviously not true for `get`.  Everything I'm about to say applies if you replace "all" with "get", it'll just narrow that handler down to a specific HTTP verb.

So, what's the difference between `all` and `use`?

[app.all](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all) will handle incoming requests at the specified URL path regardless of the HTTP verb, just as `app.use` does.  However, how it compares the requested URL to the handler is different.  For example:

```
var r = express.Router();
r.use('/foo', function (...) { ... }); // Route A
r.all('/bar', function (...) { ... }); // Route B
```

If you make a request to `/foo/123` Route A **will** be run.

If you make a request, however, to `/bar/123` Route B **will NOT** be run.

This is because with HTTP verbs express compares the *full path*, but with 'use' it only cares about the *beginning of the url*.  Because the URL `/foo/123` begins with `/foo` Route A will run, but because `/bar/123` does not match the FULL URL, Route B will not be.  Note: You could make `.all` behave in the same way:  `r.all('/bar/*', ...)`, but `use` is easier and more appropriate for this.

So, what you would tend to mount with one vs the other is different.  For example:

```
var app = express();
var router1 = express.Router();
var router2 = express.Router();

router2.all('*', function (req, res) { ... }); // Must specify a path!

router1.use('/secondary-routes', router2); // Can't do this with all.

app.use(router1); // Look Ma, no path!
```

Here I've used `all` to handle a request coming in, where I've used `use` to mount an entire router.  Also, note that the usage of `router.METHOD` functions require a URL string as the first parameter, while `use` does not.

At the end of the day, if you:

1. Want all requests that come in under a given path (or even every request) to use the specified middleware, or
2. Want to mount an entire sub router/application, or
3. Want to include a plugin into your application

... Then `use` is probably what you want.

If you:

1. Are handling a specific request at a specific URL path (i.e. probably not doing a * match in the URL)
2. Generally won't be calling `next` and will instead actually be handling the request

... Then an HTTP verb method (like `get`, `post` or `all`) is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful explaination. But one thing about the URL match: is this matching just like regex match? I do not quite sure my understanding about this, if I want .all  to match /bar/xxx/ but not /bar/xxx and not /bar/xxx/yyy and so on, how do I specify that url?

Comment: It *can* be a regex, but isn't always.  [See this](http://expressjs.com/api.html#router.METHOD).  Note the different formats a URL might take.

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite follow this, what should I particularly pay attention to note?

Comment: Paths in express can be `/foo` or `/foo/:bar` or `/foo/:bar(\\w+\.\.\\w+)`.  These are not all regex's, the URL matching in express is more complex than that.

Comment: To answer your first comment after edit, `router.all('/bar/xxx/')` will match no other routes and the trailing slash will be required.  It will NOT handle `/bar/xxx/yyy`.

Comment: Another question I am wondering about next() is: when we reach next(), it means the request is gonna passed to next middleware or request handler, is that right? If so, I wonder what happen if I have some code which add attribute to req, will it report error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78560/discussion-between-adam-terlson-and-kuan).

Answer (score 1):

`.use` is used in 2 cases, middlewares and "modular mountable route handlers".

In your example

```
router.use('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Welcome");
});
```

This means that any requests sent to `/hello` will be terminated with "Welcome" and the actual `.get` attached to `/hello` will not be called.

So, in short, call `use` when you need to apply some general middlewares or want to do modular architecture with routers. `use` can be "used" as request handlers, but you shouldn't because it is not designed for that purpose

Comment: Thanks, Just to verify my understanding is right: so the main diff is that .use() can make a middleware which works similar to how .get/.post/... works but more general cos it will apply its request handling to all which mount to its url?

Comment: As far as I know, Yes