# express router similar routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I need to have two routes, they are similar in the start but different in ends, how can I enforce the exact pattern for the respective route to be called.

Edit - Actually the problem lies in the `app.use` statement, I've not reached the get route yet.

A)

`app.get("/admin/event/:id/sessions", function(request, response){`

B)

`app.get("/admin/event/:id", function(request, response){`

C)

```
app.use("/admin/event/:id", function(request, response, next){
```

D)

```
app.use("/admin/event/:id/sessions", function(request, response, next){
```

C is getting called for the request `GET /admin/event/1/sessions`, my expectation is that D should be getting called. Please advise.

Comment: You've noted your expectations, but haven't explained what's happening instead? The route under `A` should match the `GET` path you mentioned. Is it not?

Comment: yes for some reason, the B is getting called for `GET /admin/event/1/sessions`, I've app.use in place for both of calls as well, i hope it shouldn't conflict

Comment: [`app.use()` is intended for adding middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js), not for routes. Its path is instead a *prefix* with an assumed wildcard at the end and applies to all methods (`GET`, `POST`, etc.).

Comment: Can I restrict `app.use` to stay within it's jurisdiction only

Comment: "Every request starting with a partial path" is its jurisdiction.

Comment: Any lateral thinking? I need to have a different middle ware for subpaths,

Comment: You can provide middleware to the [routing methods](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.METHOD) to have them apply to specific routes -- `app.get('/path', someMiddleware(), function (req, res) { ... });`.

Comment: sounds promising, I'm going to try this one :)

Comment: need another trick... :) is there a way to have multiple functions getting executed for the same route, `app.get("/param1"..` and another place, `app.get("/param1`, reason to use different functions for content negotiation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation. Reason: They are different modules for the same resource type but different contents