# Using Express Static to serve SVG files

Tags: node.js, express, svg, http-headers, httpresponse

In my express app, I am trying to display an svg on the client side from the server side. The SVGs I'm serving come from the directory, /svg_library, which contains 3 svgs:

/svg_library

- svg1.svg
- svg2.svg
- svg3.svg

In order to serve svg1.svg to the client, I use `app.use(express.static('svg_library'))`.

The client then has access at localhost:3000/svg1.svg.

Question 1: how do I serve **just a single** file (svg1.svg), so that a user cannot have access to the other files (svg2.svg and svg3.svg) in svg_library?

Question 2: From an efficiency and security perspective, is it better to use express.static or directly serve the svg in the http response (changing the content-type to img/svg+xml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for Q1: You can create a middleware to filter the static resources.

E.g.

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const ignoreFiles = ['/svg2.svg', '/svg3.svg'];

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.url);
  if (ignoreFiles.includes(req.url)) {
    return res.sendStatus(403);
  }
  next();
});
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'svg_library')));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Testing via `curl`:

```
⚡  curl http://localhost:3000/svg1.svg                              
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg> %                                                                                                                                    
⚡  curl http://localhost:3000/svg2.svg
Forbidden%                                                                                                                                  
⚡  curl http://localhost:3000/svg3.svg
Forbidden%
```

Answer for Q2: From [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) doc:

> For best results, use a [reverse proxy](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#use-a-reverse-proxy) cache to improve the performance of serving static assets.

Also, see this

- [express.static vs. res.sendFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425284/express-static-vs-res-sendfile)
- [What's the better approach: serving static files with Express or nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796056/whats-the-better-approach-serving-static-files-with-express-or-nginx)