# What is the correct syntax for displaying MongoDB images in my MERN frontend using multer?

Tags: mongodb, mern, multer

I am trying to make a get request to receive the posts that exist in my MongoDB. I am using multer middleware and am struggling to display the images in the frontend.

My backend code looks like:
(posts.js)

```
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import Posts from "../models/posts.js";


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/create").post(upload.single('file'), async (req,res)=>{
  try {
    const post = new Posts({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      amt: req.body.amt,
      artist_name: req.body.artist_name,
       // Use fileType instead of req.body.type
      
      art_image: req.file.filename,
    });

    const savedPodcast = await post.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedPodcast);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

router.route("/feed").get( async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const getPosts = await Posts.find();
    console.log(getPosts)
    res.json(getPosts);
   
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error fetching posts", error });
  }
});


export default router
```

This code is tied to `app.use('/feed', feedRoute)` and gets called. My get request retrieves the data in my database correctly as:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6479438fdf4ff1fc5cf2eab8"),      
    artist_name: 'sad',
    title: 'gfds',
    description: 'adf',
    amt: '234',
    reportCount: 0,
    upvote: 0,
    createdAt: 2023-06-02T01:19:02.297Z,
    art_image: '1685668751687-event_juntion.png',       
    apply_watermark: true,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

However, I am not able to understand how to use the `art_image` file path to display it in front end. What should I write in the `src` of the `img` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serve uploaded files from the server.

You could serve entire `uploads` folder as a [static folder](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

and then add `art_image` value to the `src`:

```
<img src="1685668751687-event_juntion.png" />
```

(you can also add a virtual path):

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

```
<img src="images/1685668751687-event_juntion.png" />
```

Or, you could serve each file with [sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) upon each request, by adding a new route, which would take file name via [req.params](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters), and that approach wouldn't make the whole uploads folder accessible:

```
app.get("/images/:image", (req, res) => {

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', req.params.image));

});
```

```
<img src="images/1685668751687-event_juntion.png" />
```

See more which option would suit you:

[express.static vs. res.sendFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425284/express-static-vs-res-sendfile)