# cannot get / in a simple node file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I am trying to do a simple node / angular example of a book got. However i get an error when loading the page: cannot GET /

Anyone knows what i am doing wrong? Thanks

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('./static')).
    use('/images', express.static( '../images')).
    use('/lib', express.static( '../lib'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var days=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
          'Thursday', 'Friday'];
var serviceDays = days.slice(0);
app.get('/reset/days', function(req, res){
  serviceDays = days.slice(0);
  res.json(serviceDays);
});
app.post('/remove/day', function(req, res){
  if (serviceDays.length > 2){
    serviceDays.splice(serviceDays.indexOf(req.body.day), 1);
    console.log(days);
    res.json(serviceDays);
  }else {
    res.json(400, {msg:'You must leave 2 days'});
  }
});
app.listen(8081);
```

Comment: which error you get? that's a key information to understand what you are doing wrong...

Comment: Might want to look this over.  http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html Usually you get that error because of an incorrect route.

Comment: Also just to be sure.. Can you post the URL that you are trying to go to?

Comment: I go to localhost:8081

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you doing a `.get()` for this path `/`, which is the same as `localhost:8081`. Try doing something like this in your code.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  serviceDays = days.slice(0);
  res.json(serviceDays);
});
```

This is the same as what you have here

```
app.get('/reset/days', function(req, res){
  serviceDays = days.slice(0);
  res.json(serviceDays);
});
```

So if you go to `localhost:8081` or `localhost:8081/reset/days`, you should get the same result. What the message `cannot GET /` is saying is that there is no route set up for the requested url.

**Also note:** It looks like you are using `app.use('/', express.static('./static'))` in your code. But it looks like this is just defining all of your static routes for "static", "images", and "lib".

Here is some more info on `.use` vs `.get`

1. [Difference between app.use and app.get in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js)
2. http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use
3. http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get