# When to use app.use and when to use app.all?

Tags: node.js, express

In the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), there is the following example:

```
app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
  next()
})
```

and it explains that *the function is executed for any type of HTTP request on the `/user/:idpath`*.  This confuses me as it looks like `app.use` does the same work as `app.all()`.  Are they the same?

In describing app.use, the documentation always uses the terms `mount` and `path`.  Whereas for app.get, the term used is always `route`. What do all these mean?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between app.use and app.get in express.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js)

Answer (score 0):

app.use is typically used for middleware (like cors or a logger). Use app.get when you need to make a get request on your resource.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says     `app.use(....)`     is executed for ANY type of HTTP request on the     `/user/:id`     path whereas the     `app.get(...)`     (as an example of     `app.METHOD`    ) handles (specifically) GET request made to the given path, same applies to     `app.post()`     which ONLY handles HTTP post request.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the router is just another function. Typically router expects
mount path not being visible; otherwise in *your router you need to repeat
the mount path.*

```
router with app.use("/users", router)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {});
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {});

router with app.get("/users", router)
router.get('/users/', function(req, res) {});
router.get('/users/test', function(req, res) {});
```

in order to use the router with .get the mounting path is repeated making
it much less useful.

```
   app.use( "/product" , mymiddleware);
// will match /product
// will match /product/cool
// will match /product/foo
```

**Notice the difference between use and get? These mean different things in Express.js:**

- use means “Run this on ALL requests”
- get means “Run this on a GET request, for the given URL”

Comment: Thanks. My question was on your word `Run`.  What is `Run`?  Both app.use and app.METHOD perform the same `Run`?

Comment: in other word u can say handle request in use all request handle /product, /product/name

Comment: I have just found that there is `app.all()`.  Is `app.use` then same as `app.all()`?