# Node.js w/ Express not Picking Up Request from Angular App

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to perform a GET request from my Angular app controller when the "Send" button is pressed, as follows:

```
var config = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/sendmail',
  params: {
    from: $scope.name,
    email: $scope.email,
    message: $scope.message
  }
};

$http(config).then(function (res) {
  console.log("this message is successfully printed!");
});
```

In my Node.js Express app, I have:

```
app.get('/sendmail', function (req, res) {
  // This should print, but never does.
  console.log("Got mail!");
});
```

Why do you think the Express function is not picking up the call, even though the Angular app is sending it?

Comment: Your URL is ``/send`` in the Angular script, but ``/sendmail`` in Express.

Comment: No... sorry, I am doing it correctly in my code.. I just mistyped here. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: Have you tried sending request to your sever outside Angular app? e.g. accessing it directly in browser?

Comment: @bartekfr yes, I tried in the browser directly.... but it still doesn't call the function... and it seems to me that my angular ui-router is interfering

Comment: @bartekfr I just tried making the request from postman... and I was surprised to see that I am getting my entire page HTML back! That may tell us something....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe somewhere in your server code you set serving 'index.html' for all requests (normal practice for SPA)? You should make sure that your code handling `GET /sendmail` is placed before code which serves `index.html`

Comment: Oh amazing! That was exactly the problem! Thank you so much man. However, can you tell me one more thing... what's the difference between `app.use` and `app.get`. Since, within my node app.js, I am using `app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});`... would it make any difference to use `app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});` instead?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use - It's for middleware, such as doing something specific for every request.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) regarding differences between `use` and `get` check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz Yes, most certainly. :)