# app.get() is not working. related to Difference between app.use and app.get in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

I created express-generator. Then I tried to change `app.use('/', indexRouter)` → `app.get('/', indexRouter)` and `app.use('/users', usersRouter)` → `app.get('/users', usersRouter)`.

Then `app.get('/', indexRouter)` was working(can hit the URL and get the page information). But `app.get('/users', usersRouter)` was NOT working. This returned 404 (NotFoundError: Not Found).

I already read this question[Difference between app.use and app.get in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js)
 But I couldn't understand

**./routes/index.js**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();

 /* GET home page. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

**./routes/users**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `app.get` shouldn't be used in conjunction with a router given the router may have multiple routes using different verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.use` is designed for middlewares and `app.get` is designed for GET requests. Middlewares are functions that are called before the controller. You may have a middleware to check if the user is authenticate or not, and accept the user's request or deny it.

When you have `app.use('/', indexRouter)`, the `indexRouter` will be called for all your requests on all your routes. It is like `/*`.

When you have `app.use('/users', usersRouter)`, the `usersRouter` will be called for all your requests on all routes that start with `/users`. It is like `/users*`.

This is how you can do a GET request:

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
  message: 'It works.',
}));
```

Comment: why only " app.get('/users', usersRouter)" is not working?

Comment: You should pass a function to the `app.get`, like: `app.get('/users', getUsers)`

Comment: I have updated the answer and included a working GET request on the route `/users`

Comment: When you configure an `app.get` you should pass a route and a function to be called when the route is accessed via GET. Copy the `app.get` from the answer and try it out.

Comment: I tried it from your answer. And It works
But why `app.get('/', indexRouter)` is working? `indexRouter` is also not function

Comment: What is the content of this file >> `./routes/index` ?

Comment: I uploaded ./routes/index in question.  please check

Comment: Oh, now I got it. `indexRouter` will be called for every request. If the request matches any of the `app.get` inside the `indexRouter`, the matched will be called as well.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean

Comment: Even when you do a GET request on your `/users`, the `indexRouter` will be checked if any of its routes matches the `/users`. Because `indexRouter` is a middleware on the root `/`.

Comment: I understand it from you and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582736/10145453).I appreciate you

Comment: It may be useful to add app.get(/, ..) before static middleware, then add app.get(/*, ..) after