# Logging upon receiving POST request in Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

I have recently started picking up Node.js with the Express framework. I created a simple server and attached an HTML file with a form consisted of a single button of type submit which was supposed to send a post request to the server. It doesn't give me any errors but when I try to log a message to the console upon pressing the submit button, nothing happens. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the HTML form syntax but I can never be too sure. Here is the HTML:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Test</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <form class="test" action="http://localhost:8000/example" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="but" value="Press me">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Express code:

```
const http = require("http");
const app = require("express")();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/example", (req, res) => {
console.log("pressed");
});

app.listen(8000, ()=>{
console.log("Running at 8000");
});
```

Comment: Use, `app.use(__dirname + "/")` if you want that to be your public display folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's occurs because `app.use ()` is treated as middleware for your application. To work properly you should use `app.get ()`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601856/8858168) is more detailed explanation. Other alternative is provide your html as an static content, you can see more about [here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

To work properly you should change your code to this:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__ dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

You can also modify your HTML to this:

```
<form class="test" action="/example" method="post">
```

Because is in the same host. You just use complete url when performing action to other host.

Answer (score 1):

Change this...

```
app.use("/", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

to this...

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

Comment: Can I somehow make it not transfer me to another page f. e. the /example, its only there because I thought it would fix the issue but it didn't, I'd like to keep the current page. And also how did that solve my problem?