# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ss' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

index.html will be our main source page and
Employees.html will be where our result ends up.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ss' of undefined

let rating =req.body.ss; (error in this code)

help please ><

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
app.get(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
})
app.post('/Employees', function (req, res) {
  const sql = require('mssql')
  var config = {
    server: 'DESKTOP-4PFMKKM',
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'yaser123456',
    database: 'Company',
    port: 1433,
    options: {
      encrypt: false,
      'enableArithAbort': true
    }
  }
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    let sqlRequest = new sql.Request()
    let rating = req.body.ss
    console.log(rating)
    let sqlQuery = 'select * from Employees where rating = ' + parseInt(rating)
    sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      console.log(data)
      console.table(data.recordset)
      console.log(data.rowAffected)
      console.log(data.recordset[0])
      res.send(data)
      sql.close()
    })
  })
})
const webserver = app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log('node web server is runung ')
})
```

i want send data from form to Employees.html through index.html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/Employees" method="post">
  <h1>welcome to the Employess Query System</h1> <br/> <br/>
  select an Employees Rating: <select name="ss" id="ss">
  <option value="0">Not rated</option>
  <option value="1">poor</option>
  <option value="2">Fair</option>
  <option value="3">Average</option>
  <option value="4">Excelient</option>
</select>
  <input type="submit" id='query' value='Get Results'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binding middleware you should use `app.use`

Change the following line

```
app.get(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

to

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

[For more information look at this very detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601856/10781526)