# Express JS (Node): adding the prefix to routes is not working

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I am building a web application using the Node JS Express JS framework. Now, I am trying to add a prefix to all the routes of my application. But it is not working.

This is how I did it.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
const apiRouter = express.Router()

apiRouter.use('/api', () => {
  app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Auth route")
  })

  return app;
})
```

When I go to the '/api/auth' in the browser, I am not getting the expected response. I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot GET /api/auth
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `app.use` is to add middleware(to specific request you add for particular path) to your request and to respond by matching the exact path to it. You can read more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js) it is a very detailed thread.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
const apiRouter = express.Router();

//create route file which will handle the exact match for it;
const apiRouteHandler = require('path');

app.use('/api', apiRouteHandler)
```

Sample `apiRouteHandler`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/auth', function(req, res){
   res.send('GET route on things.');
});

//export this router to use in our index.js
module.exports = router;
```

> Cannot GET /api/auth

This errors comes in because app unable to match this route anywhere as in the middleware `app.get` won't we invoked like this. You need to create a route handler for that and then it routing mechanism of express will pass on to the correct handler in the route file.

Comment: Great to hear that! 

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `express.Router`

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

```js
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Auth route");
});

apiRouter.use('/api', router);
```

Comment: Hi are you saying that I need two instances of express router? I am already using it, apiRouter variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it simple at first:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
const apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  // handle GET /auth method
  res.send("Auth route");
});

// register handle for any request with Endpoint like /api/* (api/"anything include auth")
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port`);
});;
```