# expressJS - path values in App.use to mount a Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm confused about path in express.use.
In express document https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

it said: Path:This will match paths **starting** **with** **/abcd:**

```
app.use('/abcd', function (req, res, next) {
next()
```

})

Does this mean the '/abcd' in app.use work like regex?, which will match any url starting with /abcd (like **/abcd/efg**)
Then, it will somehow "remove" the /abcd part in the above url, and pass "/efg" to the middleware function?
(by middleware, I am referring to the router example here **app.use('/birds', birds)**
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

If so, is express.router.use(), router.get(), App.get() works the same way?

Comment: It simply means that if the path starts with `/abcd`, then the given middleware function will be called (unless prior middleware has already handled the request).

A router is just a middleware function that inspects the request and decides which of its child routes, if any, to match. The "removal" of the /abcd part is something that express.Router does to determine which of its child routes to match. It's not something that happens with all middleware.

Comment: there is already an very good answer to your question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601856/3498612

Comment: @Aurast Thank you, that's what I guess. I think the document can be more clear about the "removal" part and that App.use is "prefix-matching". Now I'm wondering if router.use() is also prefix-matching...