# Routing not working in Express. Request goes to same page

Tags: express

This is my `app.js` in `express`.

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var questionRouter = require('./routes/question');

...

app.use('/question', questionRouter); //a path  with / goes to indexRouter


app.use('/', indexRouter); //a path  with / goes to indexRouter
```

`routes/index.js` is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let index = require('../controllers/index');


router.get('/', index.index);

module.exports = router;
```

`routes/question.js` is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let question = require('../controllers/question');

router.get('/', question.question);

module.exports = router;
```

`controllers/index.js` is

```
  exports.index = function (req, res, next) {
    ...
    console.log('index2 page');//THIS GETS PRINTED 
    ...
    return response;
}
```

`controllers/question.js` is

```
exports.question = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('question page'); //THIS DOESNT GET PRINTED
    return response;
}
```

When I run the following, the request goes to `index`.

```
GET http://localhost:4000/question
Content-Type: application/json
```

When I run the following, I get `404`

```
GET http://localhost:4000/question/question
Content-Type: application/json
```

Why am I not able to reach `question`?

Comment: why use next is it middlewares you are creating? If yes why you define `question.question` you can simply do this `const {question} = require('../controllers/question');` and what that response coming from it looks like you didn't define remove the response and use this `res.json({message: "this is question"})`

Comment: and also `router.get('/', question);` Check if its work and please comment

Comment: I have made a new express app with your posted code and it accesses the question page correctly. So, I can't reproduce the problem from the posted code alone. So, the problem seems to lie somewhere else.

Comment: @Geshode He has more code inside but he doesn't want to show us and I also don't see any problem with rather proper formatting of the code.

Comment: thanks folks. Being very new to `react`, I didn't know the difference between `app.get` and `app.use`. Using only `app.get` solved the issue. This question helped - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js