# Where's the documentation on 'use' and 'next'?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I'm looking at the [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) documentation, and there doesn't appear to be any documentation on the `.use` method or anything that describes what `next()` does (the secret 3rd parameter to `use`). Am I blind, or where can I find this info?

Comment: You aren't blind.  Check out the documentation for [Express](http://expressjs.com) what works there should work with connect - express uses connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked this documentation:- http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/proto.html#app.use

`next()` is naming convention used when passing [callbacks](http://howtonode.org/control-flow)

Comment: How did you find that? Doesn't appear to be linked from the homepage.

Comment: Its not that you are blind. You tried with Google and I trusted Stackoverflow!!!! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321635/node-js-express-what-is-app-use

Comment: I thought Express was built on Connect, not the other way around...seems odd that the derived library should document it, but not the base. Or...maybe I'm misunderstanding. Connect is just a bunch of middleware of Express?

Comment: @Mark You're correct that Express is built on Connect, but not that Express defines any middleware. Express is primarily the router while the built-in middleware generally comes from Connect and [is just copied](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.3.7/lib/express.js#L41-L51). The [copies in the documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware) are for convenience.