# app.get('/') data doesn't show in same url using app.use('/') in express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, router

> This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js) is explaining difference with `app.use` and `app.get`. But not explaining about same route problem. So I want to ask my question.

I made react project with `create-react-app` and make server inside `src` folder. I want to show text in the `index.html` when url is root. So I write codes like this.

public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Html test</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

src/server/server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('<p>Hello index</p>');
});

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('Hello CodeLab');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Express is listening on port', port);
});
```

package.json

```
"babel-node": "babel-node src/server/server.js --presets es2015"
```

I test,

`localhost:4000/hello` --> Hello CodeLab

`localhost:4000/` --> Html test (**not Hello index**)

I thought `app.use` is just static file which called every time when same url is called by `app.get`. Why `app.get('/')`doesn't show `<p>Hello index</p>` in this project?

Comment: Swap the order. First in line gets the prize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between app.use and app.get in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why `app.get('/')` doesn't show `<p>Hello index</p>` in this project?

It depends on the order. Re-write like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('<p>Hello index</p>');
});
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));
```

You will get `<p>Hello index</p>` for sure!

The reason is under the hood, `app.use()` and `app.get()` both behave just like middlewares, they are treated equally in the Express app. The appear order decides which one is executed first.

Comment: Then how can I show content both "Html test" in index.html and "Hello index" in server response ?

Comment: both? It seems impossible cuz the server only response once for each request

Answer (score 0):

an app is an object initialized on the start of express. app.use is for setting midleware [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321635/nodejs-express-what-is-app-use)

to resolve this problem just remove match for a route:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));
```

With '/' in app.use you must use next() method then express will go to next controller.