# when to use app.use() in Node express app

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying to comprehend when do we need to use **app.use** in our node Express

While searching on web, I stumbled on this answer on [reddit stating the difference between](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/8lr91w/appuse_vs_appget/) app.get and app.use

Based on which, I was able to summarise the following things.

`app.use` act as a super route or middleware? meaning that it gets called on every route written below/after `app.use`?

Also, would appreciate if someone could add more information/practise about app.use.

Comment: it's duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321635/nodejs-express-what-is-app-use

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using ExpressJS with NodeJS you can use `app.get` and `app.use` for several useful aspects.

After initializing your App like `let app = express();`, you can find below some examples:

### app.use(...)

As you correctly pointed, it is useful for "middlewares", **it will apply to all the GETs, POSTs, etc. you indicate afterwords**. For example, you can use a Middleware only before the GETs you want to be "with user/pass authentication".

- Indicate the folder for static contents: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`
- Including a parser for JSON contents: `app.use(bodyParser.json());`
- Define the "Cookie Parser" signing string: `app.use(cookieParser("Signing text example"));`
- Separate Routers for your URLs in different files: `app.use("/api", apiRouter);` or `app.use("/news", newsRouter);` or `app.use("/", siteRouter);`
- For a custom error handler: `app.use(sites404handler);` or `app.use(globalErrorHandler);`

### app.get(...)

When talking about `app.get(...)` you are indicating which URLs will be visited via a GET method. But you can use several options here:

- Indicate you have a home page: `app.get("/", function(req, res) { res.send("Hello world!"); });`
- Accept POST requests: `app.post("/", function(req, res) { res.send("Hello world! With POST call."); });`
- You can also separate it in another file as "apiRouter.js" and include there: `let router = express.Router(); router.route("/books").get(function(req, res) { res.send("/api/books/ called via a Router"); });`

### app.set(...)

Remember that you also have the option `app.set(...)`. This is useful for example to define View Engines like Handlebars (.hbs files).

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 2):

1. Use for static path

   ```
   //Set static path
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
   ```
2. use as router

   ```
   //user
   app.use('/', require('./controllers/user'));
   ```
3. use for handline middleware

   ```
   //Body-parser
   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
       extended: true
   }));// Body parser use JSON data
   ```
4. Use for custom middleware

   ```
   // force https
   app.use ( (req, res, next) =>{
       if (req.secure) {
           // request was via https, so do no special handling
           next();
       } else {
           // request was via http, so redirect to https
           res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Malay, Just to confirm. 
Saying this would be correct: **app.use act as a super route or middleware? meaning that it gets called on every route written below/after app.use?**

Comment: it can be use as both, even router is also a middleware :)

Comment: @KuchBhi to use `app.use()` as a super router the first param is `/`, that is the top route

Answer (score 1):

`app.get` route handler [is applied to GET requests](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get.method), either for specified paths or all paths:

> Routes HTTP GET requests to the specified path with the specified callback functions.

`app.use` middleware [is applied to all requests](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use), either for specified paths or all paths:

> Mounts the specified middleware function or functions at the specified path: the middleware function is executed when the base of the requested path matches path.

`use` is used to apply some logic (middleware) to specific route or entire application, regardless of request method.