# Express.js application bug: the browser is stuck in loading state when trying to access certain route

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

For a reason I have been unable to identify, when (in the browser) I try to go to: `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` it (the browser) get stuck in a loading state and never  actually loads the dashboard route.

In the "entry" index.js file I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const app = express();

dotenv.config();

//Conect to MONGODB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(() => {
    console.log('conected');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`);
});

// Set static directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Set views directory
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Use Express Layouts
app.use(expressLayouts);

// Middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Bring the Posts Routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');

// Get Posts
app.use('/', postsRoute);

// Get Single Post
app.use('/:id', postsRoute);

// Bring the Dashboard
const dashboardRoute = require('./routes/admin/dashboard');

// Get Dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`));
```

In the **dashboard route** (routes\admin\dashboard.js) I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const dashboardController = require('../../controllers/admin/dashboard');

// Express router
const router = express.Router();

// Dysplay Dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', dashboardController.displayDashboard);

module.exports = router;
```

While in the **dashboard controller**:

```
const Post = require('../../models/post');

exports.displayDashboard = (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Dashboard');
};
```

in `routes/front-end/posts.js` I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const postsController = require('../../controllers/front-end/posts');

// Express router
const router = express.Router();

// Get Posts
router.get('/', postsController.getPosts);

// Get Single Post
router.get('/:id', postsController.getSinglePost);

module.exports = router;
```

The **posts controller**:

```
const Post = require('../../models/post');

exports.getPosts = (req, res, next) => {
    const posts = Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
        if(err){
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        } else {
            res.render('default/index', {
                layout: 'default/layout',
                website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                page_heading: 'XPress News',
                page_subheading: 'A MEAN Stack Blogging Application',
                posts: posts
            });
        }
    });
};

exports.getSinglePost = (req, res, next) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
        Post.findById(id, function(err, post){
            if(err){
                console.log('Error: ', err);
            } else {
                res.render('default/singlepost', {
                    layout: 'default/layout',
                    website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                    post: post
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

> **IMPORTANT:**
>   It is necessary that every **single post** is displayed under the **root url**, for example: `http://localhost:3000/5e3063dbfa749d9229bab26f` where `5e3063dbfa749d9229bab26f` is, of course the post id.

This is for SEO purposes. I intent to later replace id with post *slug*: `http://localhost:3000/my-great-post`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: in rounting override, `.use()` = all http verbs, `.get()` forces to only use GET verb... just change `app.get('/dashboard', ...)` to `app.use('/dashboard', ...)` as in your rounting you are specifing the `router.get` already ... `app.get('/dashboard', ...)` would only be valid if  the function you pass return just `(res, req) => { ... }` but you are retunging a `Router` type

Comment: @balexandre I get `router is not defined` error.

Comment: I've created [this code](https://github.com/balexandre/so59977566) this week for an answer, check how I did it and will work :) - you might even learn a thing or two! let us know how it went

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED IT**, for complete running example clone [node-cheat XPressBlog](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/stackoverflow_answers/express-loading-stuck/XPressBlog-master) and run `node index` followed by `npm i`.

Point browser to *http://localhost:3000/dashboard*, outputs:

> This is Dashboard

*http://localhost:3000*, outputs:

> This will load all posts; continue with your logic!

*http://localhost:3000/my-great-post*, outputs:

> This will load single post with slug : my-great-post

**What you were doing wrong?**

You were confusing the use of `app.use(`, so those are fixed as per your needs (as mentioned in your post) like this:

```
const dashboardRoute = require("./routes/admin/dashboard");
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);

const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');
app.use('/', postsRoute);
```

In case you wish to explore more about `app.use` here are the links:

- [nodejs-express-what-is-app-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321635/nodejs-express-what-is-app-use)
- [using-middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,
`app.use('/:id', postsRoute);` and `app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);` are same to the browser. Cause when the browser gets '/dashboard', it doesn't know whether the string 'dashboard' is a id or not. Because of that, it gets stuck as the URL indicates to both of these routes. So change the `app.use('/:id', postsRoute);` to `app.use('/post/:id', postsRoute);` . This will work fine.

Secondly, according to your code the URL should be `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/dashboard`, not `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const app = express();

dotenv.config();

//Conect to MONGODB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(() => {
    console.log('conected');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`);
});

// Set static directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Set views directory
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Use Express Layouts
app.use(expressLayouts);

// Middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Bring the Posts Routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');

// Get Posts
app.use('/', postsRoute);

// Get Single Post
app.use('/post/:id', postsRoute); //****changed******

// Bring the Dashboard
const dashboardRoute = require('./routes/admin/dashboard');

// Get Dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Index.js you are adding routes exports to "/" , in express routes paths will match with regular expression. so when added router to "/" so everything will be start from here.

```
// Bring the Posts Routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');

// Get Posts
app.use('/', postsRoute);

// Get Single Post
app.use('/:id', postsRoute);

// Bring the Dashboard
const dashboardRoute = require('./routes/admin/dashboard');

// Get Dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);
```

Here what is happing is 
First now route become like this

`/` you added postsRoutes

So now routes becomes

`/` - will gives all posts 
`/:id` - will gives single post

Again you added postsRoutes to ":/id"
`/:id` - postsRoutes

so now routes becomes

`/:id` will gives all posts 
`/:id/:id` will give single posts

So you have to remove any one line from those

FINE this one only

```
// Get Posts
app.use('/', postsRoute);
```

And for your dashboard you are done same thing

`app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute)`;

now routes becomes

`/dashboard/dashboard` - it will give dashboard

but this one override the "/:id/:id" routing matching so everthing now override by this one

so create another route for getting the posts like `app.use("/posts", postsRoute);`

`/posts` -> it will give all posts

`/posts/:id` -> it will give single info

---

And dashboard routes you need to change

```
router.get('/dashboard', dashboardController.displayDashboard);

/dashboard -> "/"

router.get('/', dashboardController.displayDashboard);
```

Final routes will be

```
const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');

// Get Posts
app.use('/posts', postsRoute);

// Get Single Post
// THIS ONE WILL COMMENT 
// app.use('/posts/:id', postsRoute);

// Bring the Dashboard
const dashboardRoute = require('./routes/admin/dashboard');

// Get Dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);
```

In dashboard routes

```
router.get('/', dashboardController.displayDashboard);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not configuring your routes correctly in your index.js file.
Try this:

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const app = express();

dotenv.config();

//Conect to MONGODB
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("conected");
  });

mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
  console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`);
});

// Set static directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Set views directory
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

// Set view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Use Express Layouts
app.use(expressLayouts);

// Middleware
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// Bring the Posts Routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');

const dashboardRoute = require("./routes/admin/dashboard");

// Get Dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);

// Get Posts
app.use('/', postsRoute);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

You don't need to use two postsRoutes. Check this: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Also I suggest you add your post route like so:
`app.use('/post, postsRoute).`

Answer (score 1):

Your routing issue could be fixed with replacing the order of `/:id` and `/dashboard`.

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const app = express();

dotenv.config();

//Conect to MONGODB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(() => {
    console.log('conected');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`);
});

// Set static directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Set views directory
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Use Express Layouts
app.use(expressLayouts);

// Middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Bring the Posts Routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');

// Get Posts
app.use('/', postsRoute);

///////////////////////UPDATED PART/////////////////////////////////////
// Bring the Dashboard
const dashboardRoute = require('./routes/admin/dashboard');

// Get Dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);

// Get Single Post
app.use('/:id', postsRoute);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add postRoute once in index.js,

```
// Bring the Dashboard
const dashboardRoute = require("./routes/admin/dashboard");
// Get Dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);
// Bring the Posts Routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');
// Get Posts
app.use('/', postsRoute);
```

and in the dashboardRoute file change the route to **'/'** instead of **'/dashboard'**, else you need to use **localhost:3000/dashboard/dashboard** to get the dashboard

```
router.get('/', dashboardController.displayDashboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your entry file `index.js` , you are registering the routes in the wrong way.

To register routes, you have to use `app.use()` and not `app.get()`

Hence change `app.get('/', postsRoute);` to `app.use('/', postsRoute);`

Let me know if this worked.

Edit: after looking again I saw you are adding the prefix "dashboard" twice to the route.

So change the line: `app.get('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);`

to

`app.use('/', dashboardRoute);`

Comment: I operated the changes, but the problem remained.

Comment: I think you also need to remove `dashboard` from index.js file. Try doing `app.use('/', dashboardRoute);` instead of `app.get('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);`

Answer (score 0):

> The only one reason is because you're using `get` twice. First in your `index.js` and the second one in your `dashboard.js`. You should not to do that.

So, to fix it, make sure in your `index.js` don't use `app.get`:

```
app.get('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);
```

Only use `app.use`:

```js
// Get Dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);
```

After you use set `app.use('/dashboard')` in your `index.js`, make sure in your `dashboard.js`, like this code below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const dashboardController = require('../../controllers/admin/dashboard');

// Express router
const router = express.Router();

// Dysplay Dashboard
router.get('/', dashboardController.displayDashboard);

module.exports = router;
```

Now, you can call your endpoint with url: `localhost:3000/dashboard`.

For an example of your code, you can look at my codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/express-ejs-bug-answer-0nyo9

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I operated the changes, but the problem remained.

Comment: Only change it in your `index.js`, not in `dashboard.js`.

Comment: I need to keep the code for the posts too: `// Bring the Posts Routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/front-end/posts');

// Get Posts
app.use('/', postsRoute);

// Get Single Post
app.use('/:id', postsRoute);`. As soon as I do that, the dashboard becomes inaccessible.

Comment: I can't solve your `posts` route, because you're not provide it in your question, so I don't know where's the problem and how to fix it. But for dashboard, there's an example and if you follow the dashboard, then its will working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207180/discussion-between-titus-sutio-fanpula-and-razvan-zamfir).

Answer (score 0):

You're applying 2 filters.

First in `app.get('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);`
and then in `router.get('/dashboard', dashboardController.displayDashboard);`.

So you're probably creating  `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/dashboard` route

Try removing filter from one of them

Comment: I replaced `app.get` with `app.use`.

Answer (score 0):

try to write `app.get('/:id', postsRoute);` after `app.get('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);`

when `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` url called it will call `postRoute` route instead of `dashboardRoute`, because express will recognize '/dashboard' as '/:id', so `req.params.id` should be equal to 'dashboard' inside `postRoute`

Comment: I need an _alternative_ to this solution because the application will be quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorganize your routes. Your app architecture looks confusing. If you are using express Router then you need to do something like this:

your **index.js**

```
...
const routes = require('./routes/index');
... 
// Middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use('/', routes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

you need to create **routes/index.js** file containing something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dashboardController = require('../controllers/admin/dashboard');
const postsController = require('../controllers/front-end/posts');

// Get Posts
router.get('/posts', postsController.getPosts);

// Get Single Post
router.get('/posts/:id', postsController.getSinglePost);

// Display Dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', dashboardController.displayDashboard);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I have pushed all the code I currently have to **[GitHub](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)**. Have a look. Thanks!