# app.use() routing using express-generator

Tags: node.js, express, express-generator

I'm using express-generator.

The following codes are in app.js

1- The following two routings:

```
 **app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);**
```

2- Andthe following are defined

```
  **var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
  var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');**
```

The following codes are modules:
1- users.js with the following code

```
 **var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 /* GET users listing. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
module.exports = router;**
```

2- index.js with the following code

```
  **var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();
  /* GET home page. */
  router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
     title: 'Express',
     condition: true
  });
  });
  module.exports = router;**
```

My question: if I hit the following URL     (http://localhost/)     then the
      **app.use('/', indexRouter);**       shall be called . 
and when I hit      (http://localhost/users)     the same URL shall be called which is      **app.use('/', indexRouter);**      because      **use**      finds the first matched pattern which it is     **/**   . But it calls      **app.use('/users', usersRouter)**       instead.

If it's      **get**      instead of     **use**    then its OK and making sense for me, could anybody explain this code behavior? thnx

Comment: Maybe check the answer on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321635/nodejs-express-what-is-app-use