# not able to get data from mongodb and verify data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
app.post('/templates/views/login', async(req,res) => {
    try {
      const em = req.body.email;
      const pass = req.body.pw;

      const useremail = await db.Register.findOne({
        email : em});
      
      if(useremail.pass === pw){
        res.status(201).render("index");
      }else {
        
      }

    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send("invalid email")
    }
  });
```

this is the code which i am having error with
not able to get data from mongodb and verify data  it is always giving output of invalid email

Comment: Do you have middleware to parse the request body?

Comment: I am still learning so can you tell me exactly what is middleware :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904854/what-is-middleware-exactly
There is a library called [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) that you can use which will convert the json request body into a javascript object.

Comment: oh I don't have any middleware to parse the request body