# Is there a way to have a Heroku error/maintenance url served directly without the iframe

Tags: heroku, custom-error-pages, maintenance-mode

Heroku allows you to turn "maintenance mode" on for your applications, and also allows you to specify a custom url to be served during this period.  I just tried this out and discovered that Heroku serves the custom url in an iframe.  This wasn't quite what I was expecting.

We use Heroku to host an API service, and had planned on having the custom error/maintenance pages serve json data. We're hoping that there is a way to have the maintenance url served directly.

After searching SO, Quora, and the general "internets" I haven't seen any posts asking this question, so here I am posting on SO.

Below are posts that are related to my question, but don't address it directly.

Old posts before there was any customization:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/heroku/EJRtW1XrlpU

Post asking for custom javascript in the html rendering the iframe:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/heroku/Db0JEWmuz_w

Comment: jumand, did you manage to find a way to accomplish this? I'm facing a similar problem right now.

Comment: Nope. :-/ But we haven't looked into it since then.  We spoke to a customer account manager back then, and it didn't seem like it was on the roadmap.

Comment: Here's a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42017093/242933.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to customize the error page(s) other than outlined here, which use an iFrame: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages#customize-pages

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, you can program your Heroku app so that for every request it receives, it first (before doing anything else) checks for the mere existence of a specific environment variable, eg, called `MAINTENANCE`. If set, you immediately return your custom JSON response.

For example, add the following block of code at the beginning of your [Rack app](https://rack.github.io/)'s `call` method. (For a [Sinatra app](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), you could add it at the beginning of a [before filter](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters). For a [Ruby on Rails app](http://rubyonrails.org/), you could implement this as [Rack middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256569/what-is-rack-middleware).)

```
if ENV['MAINTENANCE']
  status = '503'
  headers = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
  body = ['{"message":"The server is undergoing maintenance. Please try again later."}']
  return [status, headers, body]
end
```

Then, to turn on "[maintenance mode](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode)," set your app's `MAINTENANCE` environment variable to any value your heart desires.

```
heroku config:set MAINTENANCE=1
```

To turn off "maintenance mode," simply unset your app's `MAINTENANCE` environment variable.

```
heroku config:unset MAINTENANCE
```

Voila! Makeshift maintenance mode for a JSON REST API app.

Comment: Just notice that this is not full replacement of native Heroku maintenance mode as it does not work during app restart/scaling.