# How to implement maintenance mode for Heroku API

Tags: api, heroku, maintenance-mode

I want to use the [maintenance mode on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode).

But for an **API**, the maintenance mode does not seem to work. My API calls are stopped in their tracks because there is no header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' present. So there is no way to know if the API is in maintenance mode—or if it's just not responding.

Is there a way to use the Heroku maintenance mode when the app is an API?

Comment: If your application is in maintenance mode that it's not able to receive any web requests. I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: Well the maintenance mode serves an HTML page when you access an HTML app directly. Can't I do something similar for JSON requests from API clients? Instead of receiving a 503, the clients receive an error.

Comment: Yeah, you could use a custom maintenance page (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h17-poorly-formatted-http-response) which could return a JSON packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, unfortunately not. When you set a custom maintenance page it gets embedded as an iframe within a Heroku-served HTML page. As you've identified, the CORS headers are not set so your API client won't even fetch the page.

See [Is there a way to have a Heroku error/maintenance url served directly without the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806681/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-heroku-error-maintenance-url-served-directly-without-th)