Rails set alternative log for endpoint
Is it possible to configure an alternative log (or none at all) for a given endpoint in Rails 6.1?
I created a health check as in
https://blog.saeloun.com/2023/02/27/rails-introduces-default-health-check-controller/#before
but now my container adds 13 log lines every 10s.

There are some hackish workarounds for a different log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936358/redirect-logger-output-for-a-specific-controller-in-rails-4, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821668/redirect-logger-output-for-a-specific-controller-in-rails-3. If you just want nothing then you might be able to use ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence#silence
