# Run Raw SQL in Rails after connecting to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vertica

I'd like my Rails app to run a raw sql command after it establishes the connection to the DB. In which file does that belong? One of the config/initializers?

Comment: Curious, what are you trying to do? A little more context would definitely be helpful!

Comment: Run once? Run every time it starts up?

Comment: I'd just like it to run each time a connection is established with the DB. Specifically I'm trying to connect to a Vertica DB, which I do have a driver for, however by default Vertica has autocommit off and I need to enable it before attempting any insert/delete statements

Comment: How often does a connection happen? Remember Vertica is not an OLTP platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use monkeypatching to force strict mode for MySQL, the same approach should also work in your case. This code belongs in an initializer.

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter

private
  alias_method :configure_connection_without_autocommit, :configure_connection

  def configure_connection
    configure_connection_without_autocommit
    execute "COMMAND_TO_ENABLE_AUTOCOMMIT"
  end
end
```

For reference, here's the [source code for Mysql2Adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb#L251).

Answer (score 0):

I think You can write a rake filter, through which you can fire a query before each inbound call. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256569/what-is-rack-middleware).