# how do I run a ruby script with an event machine listener on heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, eventmachine, slack-api

I have a script which uses a gem that has `eventmachine` which listens for an API call (it's the slack-api gem).

On my dev environment, I just run `bundle exec ruby ruby_slack.rb` and the console shows that it is listening. When the API call hits, then I see the `stdout`.

How do I have this same behavior in heroku?

I created a `Procfile` which has: `web: bundle exec ruby slack.rb` but I think it's just waiting for a request from the web app to run it.

I want this to run (and keep running) listening for events.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting it up as a Rack application?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I can google it. What does this enable me to do?

Comment: Rack acts as a web server interface to your application written in ruby. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256569/what-is-rack-middleware. btw, is there any way you can show what your application looks like?

Comment: How would I show it?  There's no web interface. Is just waits for an API call in a do loop. It uses a real time API that messages and it looks like event machine picks it up and then runs it. How do I enable rack in Heroku?  Looks like I could use a config.ru file but wanted to see if there were a similar example of a persistent listener.

Answer (score 0):

You need a web server that responds on the port that Heroku asks it to respond and a thread for websocket processing. For example with Sinatra:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module MyBot
  class Web < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      'Hello world.'
    end
  end
end

Thread.new do
  # run your Slack RealTime bot here
end

run MyBot::Web
```

This is captured in [this tutorial](https://github.com/dblock/slack-ruby-bot/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md). Also generally try [slack-ruby-bot](https://github.com/dblock/slack-ruby-bot) which does all the heavy lifting for you.