# Need to restart Puma to reflect changes in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I just pushed some new changes to my newly deployed Rails 4 app. More precisely some changes in the view file.

To my desmay, after pushing the changes, the website still showed the same old view. I investigated quite a bit, and in the end I realized that the key to solving the issue was:

```
sudo restart puma-manager
```

Now, is this a normal practice? Restarting the server every time changes are pushed? Or did I configure Puma unproperly?

Can someone tell me if there is something I can do to improve this situation?

Comment: Yes, for every push I also need to restart the server to see the changes.. If you use Capistrano, there also people write puma restart task.

Answer (score 4):

autoupdate code in Rails works under the rack middleware [`ActionDispatch::Reloader`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb).

> By default, `ActionDispatch::Reloader` is included in the middleware
>   stack  only in the development environment.

When request hits the server. The middleware `ActionDispatch::Reloader` kicks in, and executes callbacks inserted.

For example:

```
=> bundle exec rake middleware RAILS_ENV=development
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x00000004b662b0>
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use Rollbar::Middleware::Rails::RollbarMiddleware
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Reloader #< -- here reloader!
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use Warden::Manager
run MyApp::Application.routes
```

and in `production` have no `ActionDispatch::Reloader`:

```
=> bundle exec rake middleware RAILS_ENV=production
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x00000004092e60>
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use Rollbar::Middleware::Rails::RollbarMiddleware
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use Warden::Manager
run MyApp::Application.routes
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand half the words in your answer... I am not familiar with terms like "rack middleware". Could you please expland a little?

Comment: Sure look [`What is Rack middleware?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256569/what-is-rack-middleware)

Comment: Rails builds with the rack stack. Rails is nothing more than several racks.

Comment: Ok, I think I have understood now why it works as it works. That was quite instructive. Thanks. But is there any way to change this?

Comment: Could you clarify please _change  this_?

Comment: As explained in the question, whenever I made changes on the code, I need to restart manually Puma. Is there a way to make this automatically?

Comment: i always prefer `restart` the server, all others technics  make your app slow... i use capistrano and have a restart server task, i don't think about it.