# How to work with fields from a join table in many-to-many relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the usual many-to-many relationship:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts_and_images
  has_many :images, through: :posts_and_images
end

class PostsAndImage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :image
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts_and_images
  has_many :posts, through: :posts_and_images
end
```

I added a field to the `posts_and_images` table. And now I can't understand how I can work with this field.

For example, I added a `description` field to the `posts_and_images` table. That is, this field with a unique description for each image of each post.

I want to work with this field like this:

```
- @post.images.each do |image|
  / ...
  = content_tag :div, image.description
```

Tell me, please, how can I achieve this result?

Comment: You mean a join table / join model? [Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256569/what-is-rack-middleware) is something very different.

Comment: @max I updated the title. That is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to start by naming the join model according to the conventions. `PostsAndImage` is just weird in every way.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_images
  has_many :images, through: :post_images
end

class PostImage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :image
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_images
  has_many :posts, through: :post_images
end
```

But you could probaly come up with better names like attachment, media, etc.

Instead of iterating through `images` you want to iterate through `post_images`:

```
- @post.post_images.each do |post_image|
  = content_tag :div, post_image.description
  # you can get the image with post_image.image
```