# Ruby on Rails Rspec undefined method host error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I try to write test to a method in controller I received `undefined method host error.` Here is the example code blocks below

In rspec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe FooController, type: :controller do

 before do
      @controller = FooController.new
      @controller.params = ActionController::Parameters.new({ foo_id: foo.id, })


      @set_foo = @controller.send(:set_foo_data)

 end
```

and in foo controller:

```
def set_foo_data
  @foo_data = {
      table_type: :foo,
      .
      .
      data_url: foos_path,
  }
end
```

data_url part causing this issue.

I checked with byebug and data_url was nil.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work is that controllers are [Rack middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256569/what-is-rack-middleware) and expect to be initialized with a request. Its also just not how you should be coding or testing your code in the first place. Bin it.

Controller specs use the `get`, `post`, etc methods that actually create an instance of the controller with a mocked request.

`get :foo` would then call the `foo` method directly on the controller instance. You do not initialize controllers directly. If you feel tempted to do this its a very good sign you're doing something very wrong.

Unit testing controllers with controller specs is an extremely flawed approach that's discouraged by both the RSpec and Rails teams - you're mocking out huge parts of the application like the middleware and routes and it lets so many bugs through your tests.

The modern way to test a Rails application is to just test the *actions* of your controller by sending HTTP requests. This means that you should ONLY test the methods that actually correspond to a route and test your application through the response it provides (the headers and body) and eventually the side effects. In RSpec-Rails this is provided through [request](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec), [feature](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/6-0/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) and [system specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/system-specs/system-spec).

Everything else in your controller like this method should be private - and you don't test privates.

Comment: Thank you max for providing information. I was tempted to test private methods such as this because of opencov does not highlight green, the inside of these methods (as if they are not tested).